# Big border arround deepin-terminal in awesome-wm

Tags: border, awesome-wm

I found this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/5pgv8o/tip_to_remove_window_borders_when_using/) to remove the big black border around the window of deepin-terminal in KDE. How can I achieve it in awesome wm? Look at the screenshot...

[Screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkoWN.png)

Answer (score 2):

i'm author of Deepin-Terminal

Git version of deepin-terminal has fixed this problem.
Git version will remove shadow when it found window manager's composited is disable.

Compile git version please check: https://github.com/manateelazycat/deepin-terminal/

Comment: Small comment: Just because some big window manager's have a built-in compositing manager does not mean that it has to be this way.

Answer (score 0):

Blame GTK, but now that I am sure you complained loudly to them ;), here's the workaround

You have to edit the GTK3 CSS to remove these borders, more information here:

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/459
https://web.archive.org/web/20160710205404/https://awesomewm.org/wiki/Customizing_GTK_Apps#For_GTK3_apps

Comment: Deepin-terminal uses gtk2 if I'm right. Modifying ~/.gtkrc does not show any effect. In terms of gtk2, which workarounds do I have to do?

Comment: If it's GTK2, then they put great effort into making it look like GTK3, even to the point of reproducing the bugs. You can always fire a compositor like `compton` or use a different theme.

Comment: Creating ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css and firing compton only make the border transparent but it's still present. In addition, albert [link](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert) which uses Qt also shows an annoying border

Comment: In both case, they are client side border. Awesome isn't told or aware of them. They have to be fixed in the application.